# After updating Expo from SDK 48 to SDK 49, the error "Error while updating property 'fontWeight' in shadow node of type: RCTText" occurs

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a Expo driven React Native application. Currently I'm using the Expo SDK 48. Since the version 49 came out, I want to upgrade my SDK version as it has many useful features.

After upgrading my SDK from v48 to v49 using the following guide ([https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740#:~:text=%E2%9E%A1%EF%B8%8F%20Upgrading%20your%20app](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740#:%7E:text=%E2%9E%A1%EF%B8%8F%20Upgrading%20your%20app)), my application crashes every time when I run `npm start`.

The crash happens with the error "Error while updating property 'fontWeight' in shadow node of type: RCTText".
[image]

I searched for solutions and I found some that are saying not to use style numbers like string. As example, rather than using `styles={{fontWeight: '20px'}}`, I should use `styles={{fontWeight: 20}}`. I am 100% sure that my project does not contain, let's say, string type style numbers.

The weird thing is that my app works perfectly with SDK 48 and this startup crash only occurs in the version 49.
I've had run the npx expo-doctor@latest command too, to check if there are any kind of issues in my dependencies, but it said everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `Expo 49`, they made changes, and now `fontWeight` is a **string**, like `fontWeight: "400"` or `fontWeight: "600"`
I'm not sure about the string, but it helped me fix the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did come across this issue but I am unsure at what point I incurred it.
This is what I had:

```js
...
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Welcome !</Text>
  </View>
</View>
...

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 700,
  },
});
```

The expected result is `Welcome !` in **bold**

- The error message `Error while updating property 'fontWeight' in shadow node of type: RCTText` indicates that there is an issue with updating the font-weight of a text element in your application.
- The error message `java.lang.double cannot be cast to java.lang.String` further clarifies that the issue is related to an incompatible data type being passed to the fontWeight property.

The solution is;

```js
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "700", //see change, "bold" works but not many recommend it.
  },
});
```

**NOTE:** If you are facing the same issue with respect to `fontSize` the solution is vice-versa, have a **number** instead of a **string**

- **SEE:** [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props?language=javascript)